# Using Custom Meta Capabilities on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I am trying to create a product post type. I have already done so and been using it successfully in the development of a product review panel. I am trying to give a certain role the ability to create and manage these products so that vendors could come in and put their own products in. I have looked in other Member Plugin and I understand it 100%. I read this post:

» [**Meta Capabilities for Custom Post Types** — JustinTadlock.com](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types#comment-2277716)

And it explains how to add the capabilities. My issue being when I create a custom post type if I make the declaration of `'capability_type' => 'product'` in the `register_post_type()` for product the post type is no longer created. As if I gave it some sort of incorrect input. I have read the Codex and this parameter is a string and defaults to `'post'`. Which works if you supply that value.

I have tried just copy and pasting the code from the aforementioned post linked above. I have tried doing this in a different install of WordPress. I have not tried doing a completely fresh install and disabling all plugins however. That is what I am going to do now. I am hoping some one has had this problem before (people in the comments on the above article have and I commented there). Here is my current post registration code

```
register_post_type( 'bounty_product', array(
  'labels' => array(
     'name' => 'Products',
     'singular_name' => 'Product',
     'add_new' => 'Add New',
     'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
     'edit' => 'Edit',
     'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
     'new_item' => 'New Product',
     'view' => 'View',
     'view_item' => 'View Product',
     'search_items' => 'Search Products',
     'not_found' => 'No Products found',
     'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash',
     'parent' => 'Parent Product'),
  'description' => 'Used for the product review section',
  'public' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'menu_position' => 20,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
));
```

To this I have tried adding bellow the `'public' => true`:

```
'capability_type' => 'product',
        'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_product',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_product',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_product',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_product',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_product',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_product',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_product',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_product',
            'read_post' => 'read_product',
        ),
```

This simply breaks the custom post and it seems to be the `'capability_type' => 'product'` line that is the problem.

Comment: To confirm I installed a fresh version of Wordpress and installed no plugins and using the default theme. I created a plugin that would create a custom post type. I can do that. But I add the line 'capability_type' and it breaks. I noticed the codex says that you have to have 'map_meta_cap' set to TRUE in order for this to work. However this does not make any difference. Please help!

Comment: There is a important remark in the explanation for capability_type at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type ... "It seems that `map_meta_cap` needs to be set to true, to make this work."

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry was a long time ago I did this and did not really know the eticite and was quite new to programming/collaboration communities! Have voted but don't have enough rep for it to show. Can confirm the answer by @ialocin is perfect and it was a life saver.. I feel really bad now for not voting earlier..

Comment: @justsayno It was indeed a little bit longer ago, but no worries, it happens. I just tend to check up on my old(er) answers to make sure the [wordpress.se] process runs smoothly. That said, if you think the answer was helpful, you could and should accept it to end the process for now - take a look at »[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)« if you do not know how to.

Comment: Sorry! I was being dumb. Thanks again truly. Was one of the first times I used a stack exchange and when I got such a thorough and helpful answer I was so stoked. Really kicked off my  own efforts to give out to the community where possible. Will stay on top of answers in future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have to **assign the capabilities manually to user roles**, otherwise your post type simply doesn't show, this is true for the administrator role too.

Taking another look at the [arguments section of the register_post_type() reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) I changed your code a bit:

- **map_meta_cap**

  - necessary

> It seems that `map_meta_cap` needs to be set to true, to make this work.

- **capability_type**

  - single and plurals array
  - not necessary

> May be passed as an array to allow for alternative plurals when using this argument as a base to construct the capabilities (...), the first array element will be used for the singular capabilities and the second array element for the plural capabilities (...).

- **capabilities**

  - not needed, because

> (array) (optional) An array of the capabilities for this post type
>   Default: capability_type is used to construct

The above is for clarification about the code changes. Besides that I added a debugging part, printing `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['bounty_product']`, because like it's mentioned in the codex reference:

> If you assign a 'capability_type' and then take a look into the $GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['your_cpt_name'] array, then you'll see the (...)

capabilities in the `[cap] => stdClass Object ( ... )` part.

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'pt_bounty_product');
function pt_bounty_product() { 
register_post_type( 'bounty_product', array(
  'labels' => array(
     'name' => 'Products',
     'singular_name' => 'Product',
     'add_new' => 'Add New',
     'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
     'edit' => 'Edit',
     'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
     'new_item' => 'New Product',
     'view' => 'View',
     'view_item' => 'View Product',
     'search_items' => 'Search Products',
     'not_found' => 'No Products found',
     'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash',
     'parent' => 'Parent Product'),
  'description' => 'Used for the product review section',
  'public' => true,
  'capability_type' => array('bounty_product','bounty_products'),
  'map_meta_cap' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'menu_position' => 20,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),

));

// uncomment /** like this /**/
/**
echo '<pre>';
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['www_product']);
echo '</pre>';
/**/
}
```

Codex: [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

You have to uncomment to see that the capabilities are associated to the post type. If you can see them that means the post type initialization and the custom capabilities work. **But** like I said in the beginning, it's seems you have to assign the capabilities manually to the according user roles.

*One - first - approach to do so - at least for the administrator role - is shown below.*

**Code:**

```
    add_action( 'init', 'add_bounty_product_caps_admin');
    function add_bounty_product_caps_admin() {
          $role = get_role( 'administrator' );

          $role->add_cap( 'edit_bounty_product' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_bounty_products' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_bounty_products' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'publish_bounty_products' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_bounty_product' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_private_bounty_products' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_bounty_product' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_bounty_products' );
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_bounty_products' );
    }
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342740/2505105
Codex: [get_role()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role) | [add_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)

Now you should be able to see, add, edit and so forth your new post type as user with administrator role. You could duplicate and change or add to that to assign capabilities to other roles.

*I decided to showcase a second - a bit different - approach how capabilities can be assigned to user roles.*

**Code:**

```
    add_action( 'init', 'add_bounty_product_caps');
    function add_bounty_product_caps() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( isset($wp_roles) ) {
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'publish_bounty_products' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_bounty_products' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_others_bounty_products' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_bounty_products' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_others_bounty_products' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_private_bounty_products' );

            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'read_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'read_private_bounty_products' );

            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'author', 'read_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'author', 'read_private_bounty_products' );

            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'contributor', 'read_bounty_product' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( 'contributor', 'read_private_bounty_products' );
        }
  }
```

Source: http://isabelcastillo.com/assign-custom-post-type-capabilities-roles-wordpress
Codex: [add_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)

Do not to double assign capabilities. Above approaches are exemplary, you have to decide how to use them in what way.

*A last addition would be how to create a specific user role*

**Code:**

```
add_action('init', 'bounty_product_author_user_role');
function bounty_product_author_user_role() {
    add_role('bounty_product_author', 'Bounty Product Author',
        array (
                'edit_bounty_product' => true,
                'delete_bounty_product' => true,
                'read_bounty_product' => true,
                'publish_bounty_products' => true,
                'edit_bounty_products' => true,
                'edit_others_bounty_products' => true,
                'delete_bounty_products' => true,
                'delete_others_bounty_products' => true,
                'read_private_bounty_products' => true,
                // more standard capabilities here
                'read' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Source: http://wp-snppts.com/create-a-custom-post-type-and-define-custom-role-capabilities
Codex: [add_role()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

---

Keep in mind the above is *exemplary*, so you should fit it to you needs. To fully understand the different parts you might have to read the source and codex links - not saying that they cover all you can know about that, but it should get you started.

---

Edit:
A general overview of available capabilities can be found at the codex page: [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Comment: Thank you! Have not tried yet but will try it now. I understand what you are saying though. Cheers

Comment: Pleasure, should be - relatively - easy now to implement what you want. @justsayno

Comment: Edit: Spoke too soon, figured it out. For future use for others. In order to allow image uplaods you need to also add '$role->add_cap( 'upload_files' );' to the role capabilities function

Comment: This is such a great answer and it clears up so many questions I've had about roles and capabilities. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Gavin My pleasure, I'm happy it holds up even all those years later.