# Allow Users to Modify Some Values of Assigned Wordpress Pods

Tags: users, user-roles, pods-framework

Each `user` can have one or many `locations`. I need each `user` to be able to edit their own `locations`, or at least some of the values within their `locations`. The location pod is related to `users` (extended). I can think of several ways to do this painstakingly through PHP but I’m thinking there’s got to be a way to do this nicely with pods and maybe another plugin that plays nicely. Anybody know of one?

UPDATE:
Here's an example to make it a little more clear:

> User `johndoe` can only update locations:
>
> - `Detroit`
> - `Chicago`
> - `Cleveland`
>
> User `janedoe` can only update locations:
>
> - `San Francisco`
> - `Los Angelas`
> - `San Diego`

So I don't just need to make it possible for `users` to update `locations`. I need them to be able to update SPECIFIC `locations` only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_meta_cap()` to set more specific capabilities for your CPT. So instead of using the built-in `edit_posts` and `edit_others_posts` capabilities you would create `edit_locations` and `edit_others_locations` - thus allowing a new custom role to edit their own locations, but not `edit_others_locations`. You may find this related question helpful: [Using Custom Meta Capabilities on Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120442/using-custom-meta-capabilities-on-custom-post-type/120511#120511)

Comment: I'm not building these post types from scratch. I'm using Pods to create them. Is there a way to make this work with Pods?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pods. Are they part of some type of framework or plugin?

Comment: Yes. https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/ It's a plugin to quickly and easily create custom post types.

Comment: Okay. I think I've figured out how to tie in the capabilities but not how to set them using an attribute value yet.